# JavaScript calculator script does't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javascript. Try to make a simple calculator using DOM. I wrote the below script, But my script gives error.
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null calculator.html:8**

Here is my Script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f_number = document.getElementById("f_number").value;
        var f_number = document.getElementById("s_number").value;

        function calculate(opa)
        {
            if(opa=='+') 
            {
                var result = Number(f_number) + Number(s_number);
            }
            if(opa=='-') 
            {
                var result = f_number - s_number;
            }
            if(opa=='*') 
            {
                var result = f_number * s_number;
            }
            if(opa=='/') 
            {
                var result = f_number / s_number;
            }
            return document.getElementById('res').value = result;
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Number</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="f_number" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second Number</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="s_number" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="+" onclick="calculate()" >
                <input type="submit" value="-" onclick="calculate()" >
                <input type="submit" value="*" onclick="calculate()" >
                <input type="submit" value="/" onclick="calculate()" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Result</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="res"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put your javascript code right before `</body>`

Comment: I put my script before </body>. Now my result show undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full example of working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Number</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="f_number" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second Number</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="s_number" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                <input type="submit" value="+" onclick="calculate('+')" >
                <input type="submit" value="-" onclick="calculate('-')" >
                <input type="submit" value="*" onclick="calculate('*')" >
                <input type="submit" value="/" onclick="calculate('/')" >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Result</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="res"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(opa)
        {
            var f_number = +document.getElementById("f_number").value;
            var s_number = +document.getElementById("s_number").value;
            if(opa=='+')
            {
                var result = f_number + s_number;
            }
            if(opa=='-')
            {
                var result = f_number - s_number;
            }
            if(opa=='*')
            {
                var result = f_number * s_number;
            }
            if(opa=='/')
            {
                var result = f_number / s_number;
            }
            return document.getElementById('res').value = result;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. I want to know why there is + before document?

Comment: `document.getElementById("f_number").value` returns value which is `string` type. We have to make it `float` type. With `+` we convert it from `string` to `float` type

Comment: Thanks for nice and easy explanation.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is excuted in the order it is encountered.

When you do `document.getElementById("f_number").value` that DOM node does not yet exist. So it returns `null`, hence the error message.

Either move your code below the referenced DOM node definitions or run your code *on document ready* or `onload`.

Answer (score 0):

It means there are no values for those items:

```
 var f_number = document.getElementById("f_number").value;
 var f_number = document.getElementById("s_number").value;
```

You need to run the script once a value is present/button is clicked as opposed to right away.

Comment: Please look again my script. I added onlclick="calculate()". Gives same error.

Comment: I put my script before </body>. Error gone. Now my result show undefined.